# What steps are required to ensure more than 1024 clients can connect to redis?

Tags: ubuntu, ulimit, redis

I require more than 1024 clients to be connected to a single redis instance at once. My redis process runs as user ubuntu. I have edited /etc/security/limits.conf to specify:

```
ubuntu soft nofile 65535
ubuntu hard nofile 65535
```

I have also ensured that the maxclients parameter in redis.conf is commented out.

What other steps must I take to ensure more than 1024 clients can connect to my redis instance, or is that all?

Thanks!

---

Edit on August 2014: See this SO question for the steps you will need to do to get this working on Ubuntu 2014.04 LTS:

[Why does redis report limit of 1024 files even after update to limits.conf?](https://serverfault.com/questions/623577/why-does-redis-report-limit-of-1024-files-even-after-update-to-limits-conf/623592#623592)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is enough.
I personally wouldn't uncomment it, but set it to a reasonable maximum your server can/should handle. Obviously that depends on what you use it for.

In any case, you can just try it out via the `redis-benchmark` tool:

> redis-benchmark -c 1024 -I

This will open 1024 parallel connections to your redis server and let them idle.

See http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks for more information