# Why does redis report limit of 1024 files even after update to limits.conf?

Tags: redis, ulimit

I see this error at the top of my redis.log file:

> Current maximum open files is 1024. maxclients has been reduced to
>   4064 to compensate for low ulimit.

I have [followed these steps to the letter](https://serverfault.com/questions/386499/what-steps-are-required-to-ensure-more-than-1024-clients-can-connect-to-redis) (and rebooted):

Moreover, I see this when I run `ulimit`:

```
ubuntu@ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX:~$ ulimit -n
65535
```

Is this error specious? If not, what other steps do I need to perform? I am running redis 2.8.13 (tip of the tree) on Ubuntu LTS 14.04.1 (again, tip of the tree).

Here is the user info:

```
ubuntu@ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX:~$ ps aux | grep redis
root      1027  0.0  0.0  66328  2112 ?        Ss   20:30   0:00 sudo -u ubuntu /usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ubuntu    1107 19.2 48.8 7629152 7531552 ?     Sl   20:30   2:21 /usr/local/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

The server is therefore running as ubuntu.

Here are my limits.conf file without comments:

```
ubuntu@ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX:~$ cat /etc/security/limits.conf | sed '/^#/d;/^$/d'
ubuntu soft nofile 65535
ubuntu hard nofile 65535
root soft nofile 65535
root hard nofile 65535
```

And here is the output of sysctl fs.file-max:

```
ubuntu@ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX:~$ sysctl -a| grep fs.file-max
sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.protected_hardlinks'
sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.protected_symlinks'
fs.file-max = 1528687
sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.cad_pid'
sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.usermodehelper.bset'
sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.usermodehelper.inheritable'
sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen_key'
```

as sudo

```
ubuntu@ip-10-102-154-226:~$ sudo sysctl -a| grep fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 1528687
```

Also, I see this error at the top of the redis.log file, not sure if it's related. It makes sense that the ubuntu user isn't allowed to change max open files, but given the high ulimits I have tried to set he shouldn't need to:

```
[1050] 23 Aug 21:00:43.572 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
[1050] 23 Aug 21:00:43.572 # Redis can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should edit your files inside `/etc/pam.d/` directory.

In your case when you run `sudo -u ubuntu /usr/local/bin/redis-server`, you should add following line to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` or to `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` in case `/etc/pam.d/sudo` includes this one:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

This should help setting configuration provided inside `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much. Sounds like a change from Ubuntu 2012.04 LTS to Ubuntu 2014.04 LTS.

Comment: Glad that helped you. Indeed my xubuntu 14.04 doesn't have this line inside /etc/pam.d/sudo. Can't check 12.04 right now.

Comment: When using systemd on Debian, see http://serverfault.com/questions/770037/debian-8-4-jessie-set-open-files-limit-for-redis-user/

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion for users finding this post whose issue is not related to pam_limits.so.  In my case, Redis was being launched via supervisord.  In this case, the method by which supervisord switched user contexts caused the new session to be run with the system default limits, not those I'd configured for the user.

The solution in that case was found [here](https://lists.supervisord.org/pipermail/supervisor-users/2011-December/001004.html).  The short of it is, you need to define the limit via ulimit -n as part of the startup command in supervisord.

Example:

```
[program:redis-a]
command=bash -c "ulimit -n 32768; exec /usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/a.conf"
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as increasing the open file limit. You need to increase maxclients in your redis.conf. It is only 10000 by default.

```
# Once the limit is reached Redis will close all the new connections sending
# an error 'max number of clients reached'.
maxclients 1024000
```

Answer (score 0):

Note for other Ubuntu users with a similar problem:

If you're starting Redis on boot, f.ex via Upstart, you can set this limit with the "limit" stanza.

So for nofile:

`limit nofile 4096 4096`