# Debian 8.4 jessie set open files limit for redis user

Tags: debian, redis, debian-jessie

When starting redis 3.0.6 (installed from jessie-backports) under Debian 8.4 jessie, I get the following warning/error:

```
18127:M 13 Apr 15:12:38.730 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
18127:M 13 Apr 15:12:38.730 # Redis can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
18127:M 13 Apr 15:12:38.730 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
```

When running `ulimit -n` as root I get:

```
65536
```

The open file limit for the redis user:

```
$ ps -u redis
PID TTY          TIME CMD
18127 ?        00:00:00 redis-server
$ sudo grep 'open files' /proc/18127/limits
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files
```

How do I increase the open files limit for the redis user, so it can set the appropriate limit for the maxclients setting? I tried editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `sysctl -w fs.file-max=2459017`, but none really worked for the redis user.

Comment: how did you install redis? (debian package, compiled source from redis.io ...), what are those 'some things' you tried?

Comment: Installed it directly from jessie-backports, clarified the things I have tried in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

limits.conf does not apply to systemd services (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=754285)

so you should:

1. edit /lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service
   and add to the [Service] section the line (after: `User=redis` and `Group=redis`)
   `LimitNOFILE=65536`
2. run: `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart redis-server`

and ... it should get the new limit

check: https://sskaje.me/systemd-ulimit/

good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I actually also tried that before, but added the line right after [Service], where it did not work (or I made another mistake).